# Store state in between module function calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables

I have the following structure:

```
app/
  test1.py
  test/
   __init__.py
   test2.py
```

I import `test2.py` in `test1.py` and use functions from `test2.py`

code is as follows:

`test1.py:`

```
import test.test2 as T


T.hello()
...
T.hello1()
```

`test2.py:`

```
d = {}
def hello():
    print('hi')
    global d
    d['1'] = 1


def hello1():
    print('hi1')
    global d
    print(d) # prints{'1': 1}
```

`test1.py` will call `hello` and after sometime call `hello1`. I want to populate the `dict` `d` in `hello` and use that in `hello1`. Using a `global` works fine but what is a better way to do this since I want to avoid `globals`. I don't want to pass `d` from `hello` to the `caller` in `test1` and then from there back to `hello1`.

What can I do to avoid `globals`. I am using `python 3.5`.

Comment: Do you have any reason to avoid putting both hello functions in a class? Two functions with shared state seem like an obvious use case for a class with an instance variable self.d.

Comment: The `test1.py` file will be imported further up (contrary to my structure which I used for simplification) so I would have to add a class in `test1.py` as well and I want to know if there is any other way?

Answer (score 3):

You could just use a class:

```
class Whatever(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}

    def hello(self):
        print('hi')
        self.d['1'] = 1

    def hello1(self):
        print('hi1')
        print(self.d)

_Someinstance = Whatever()
hello = _Someinstance.hello
hello1 = _Someinstance.hello1
```

Instead of the last three lines you could also just create and use the instance wherever you need it. These were just included to make it behave (almost) like your original.

Note that functions are objects too, so you could just assign the variable to the `hello` function:

```
def hello():
    print('hi')
    hello.d['1'] = 1

def hello1():
    print('hi1')
    print(hello.d) # prints{'1': 1} 

hello.d = {}
```

Comment: The `test1.py` file will be imported further up (contrary to my structure which I used for simplification) so I would have to add a class in `test1.py` as well which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Why? If you use exactly the code I used in my answer it should work almost like the original. That's because I added the lines `hello = _Someinstance.hello` and `hello1 = _Someinstance.hello1`. If that doesn't work you need to provide a more accurate problem description :)

Comment: If you don't want to use a class, you can make the dictionary a function argument of each of the hello functions. Just pass in the same dictionary created in test1.py, as dictionaries are passed by reference.

Comment: @csunday95 yes, I am tempted to use that approach.

Comment: @MSeifert I agree, my description isn't good enough to warrant why I want to avoid using a class. Just wanted to know if there is a sane way to do this without using classes.

Comment: Normally decorators aren't a problem if they work for methods as well as functions. But you can also decorate them after "binding": `hello = your_decorator(_Someinstance.hello)`. However the second approach probably won't work anymore then.